# That just went 0 - 60 real fast

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man named Steve with a broken-down car is pulled off next to a highway. Suddenly, around 20 feet away from the him, at the edge of the forest near the highway he sees a man on horse.

The man also sees Steve, and calls out to him. "Hey mister," he says. "Wanna bet my horse here can get to 60 in less than ten seconds?"

Steve chuckles at this, knowing full well that a horse can't reach a speed of 60 miles per hour. But the man on the horse is able to complete the task.

How is it possible that the man on the horse accomplished this?

Hint:

> They are in the state of Arizona.

Comment: Kind of right away I knew it didn't mean 60 miles per hour.

Comment: It could mean 60 centimeters per hour, mile marker 60 as pointed below, or pretty much any other 60 you can think of.

Comment: @JoeZ. Oh well. I'll try to phrase my next riddle in a more difficult way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The horse indeed can get to:

> *Highway* 60 in under ten seconds, not 60 mph. The man was pulled over on the side of Route 60 in Arizona.

Comment: Dang! That was fast. Nice job.

Comment: You mean U.S. 60 right?

Comment: I was gonna answer mile marker 60, which could be done, too.

Comment: @ev3commander Thanks, yes. Made the change.

Comment: I was thinking 60 fph :P (60 feet per hour)

Comment: @ev3commander Yeah, totally legitimate solution as well. There are many.

Answer (score 10):

He rode the horse off the side of the Grand Canyon (or any other tall cliff).

The horse fell for 36 meters (2.76 seconds) after which it was going 60mph.

Comment: In a vacuum, though.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yup. But that's noise on the answer, not a disqualifier.

Comment: i like this better than the real solution :D